# Retrieving time period t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure set up in such a way as to get the results for today

so

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME
SET @Start = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @End = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1)

PRINT @Start
PRINT @End
```

gives me the time period

```
May 30 2016 12:00AM
May 31 2016 12:00AM
```

How can I modify the clause as to give me the period

```
 May 29 2016 5:30PM(Previous day)
 May 31 2016 12:00AM(Today)
```

Kind regards

Comment: So you want `@Start = Now - 24hours? ` As in `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())` ?

Comment: Thats the one...did manage though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SET @Start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)))

SET @End = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME
SET @Start = GETDATE()-1
SET @End = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1)

PRINT @Start
PRINT @End
```

Comment: Never use `GETDATE()-1`

Comment: @ChaosLegion any specific reason?

Comment: It's not among the best practices and one must learn to stop using it as soon as possible. Refer this [link](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/34594). I am sure you'll find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks @ChaosLegion :) Indeed helpful article

Answer (score 1):

```
dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
```

May be just use the DateAdd like above.